# Добавить всем числам без знака в столбце знак минус Google Sheet

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Всем привет,вопрос следующий какой написать скрипт,чтобы в столбце все числа без знака-получили знак минус
То есть,например:

> +1 000,00
>
> 160
>
> +2 500,00
>
> 90
>
> 85
>
> 85

Нужно чтобы было так:

> +1 000,00
>
> -160
>
> +2 500,00
>
> -90
>
> -85
>
> -85

Comment: У числа не может быть знака +. В ячейке или текст, или знак отображается с помощью формата ячейки. Уточните.

Comment: В ячейке текст.

Answer (score 0):

В свободный столбец:

```
=ЕСЛИ(ЛЕВБ(A2)="+";A2;"-"&A2)
```

Протянуть формулу. Выделить полученные значения, копировать, **вставить как значения** в исходный столбец. Вспомогательный столбец удалить.